# can't connect to urls ending with .tv using Jsoup

Tags: java, dom, jsoup, html-parsing

I tried to Parse the web pages ending with `.tv` and `.mobi` extension but every time I tried I end up with the same error. Jsoup can easily parse the websites ending with `.com`, `.org` , `.in` etc but not `.tv` or `.mobi`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;


public class sample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Document doc =Jsoup.connect("http://www.xmovies8.tv").get();
    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println(title);

  }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://www.xmovies8.tv
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:598)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)
    at eric.sample.main(sample.java:30)
    /home/azeem/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

And Also it failed to parse:

- http://www.xmovies8.tv
- www.fztvseries.mobi

is there any solution in Jsoup so that i can connect to different websites ending with `.mobi` , `.tv` , `.xyz` etc?

Comment: You should format your stack trace as code as well...

Comment: how can I improve my stack trace here ? . Excuse me , I am a newbie here, I have pasted the same Generated Output from my netbeans

Comment: Just do it as you have done with your code... Select all the stack trace and click on the button that formats it as code... That's just a way to improve the readability of your post and with that it also increases the likelihood of someone giving you an answer :)

Comment: @Raven I'm trying to build a web crawler that can crawl websites using JSoup. Any Suggestion would you like to give will be indeed very helpful . :) thanks.!

Comment: I actually don't have a clue about JSoup... I just reviewed your post and wanted to give you some advice in order to improve your (future) post(s)

Comment: Thanks.. A lot thats very nice of you..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't anything to do with the TLD of the domain you're attempting to scrape, infact, it's nothing to do with the name at all, or even Jsoup.

If you read your stack trace, you will see you're getting a response code of:

[`HTTP 403 Forbidden`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), which according to [HTTP Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error), means your request was seen by the web server, and deliberately refused.

Now, this could be for a number of reasons that all depend on the website you're trying to scrape.

It could be that the website sees you are trying to scrape, and they have explicitly gone out of the way to prevent being scraped

It could also be that that page requires a permission you don't have, or you need to be logged in.

I also noticed that particular domain uses [`CloudFlare`](https://www.cloudflare.com/), so it could be that CloudFlare is intercepting your request before it's even reaching the website itself.

I would make sure it's not against the website's policy to scrape them, and if it isn't, try maybe changing the User-Agent Header of your scraper to a normal browser User agent instead of java and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks  a lot @zack6849 ..!!! The problem is partially solved now . Now I can scrape other websites by adding the userAgent . But I still get HTTP 503 response for http://www.xmovies8.com which means that the website is down. Most of the time the website shows retry for the live version option . Do you have any possible solution how do I scrape those kind of websites that often give retry for live version ?
Thanks Again

Comment: You're probably getting that message because cloudflare is blocking your bot, i don't know of a way to easily get around cloudflare, unfortunately, but that's kind of the point of their service :)